# Computing the residues for $\frac{1}{z^3-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I'm struggling to follow this example in my lecture notes where they compute the residue for $\frac{1}{z^3-1}$. I understand how to get to the singularities $c=1$, $c=\exp^{2i\pi/3}$ and $c=\exp^{4i\pi/3}$.

I also understand how the steps go from L'Hopital's rule to obtain the limit as $z$ tends to $c$, which gets $\frac{1}{3c^2}$. But the notes rather helpfully stop here.

This hasn't found the residues, right?

I had a look on Mathematica, the singularity $c=1$ gives a residue of $0$, so why if you were to "sub-in" $c=1$ into $\frac{1}{3c^2}$ would you get $\frac{1}{3}$? Is it the Mathematica code I'm doing wrong or am I missing something completely?

I'm really confused how to get to this last step! Thanks in advance for any tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this example in *Mathematica* and got the answer $\frac13$:

```
 Residue[1/(z^3-1),{z,1}]
```

This is of course not surprising because the answer $\frac1{3c^2}$ is correct.

Comment: That’ll be my Mathematica coding then! Thank you for clearing that up. I’ve just realised that I put in (z^3-1) instead. What a numpty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $c\in\left\{1,e^{2\pi i},e^{4\pi i}\right\}$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=c}\left(\frac1{z^3-1}\right)=\frac1{3c^2}.\tag1$$That's because\begin{align}\lim_{z\to c}(z-c)\frac1{z^3-1}&=\lim_{z\to c}\frac1{\frac{z^3-1}{z-c}}\\&=\frac1{\lim_{z\to c}\frac{z^3-1}{z-c}}\\&=\frac1{3c^2}.\end{align}It follows from this that, near $c$, you can write $\frac1{z^3-1}$ as$$\frac1{3c^2(z-c)}+a_0+a_1(z-c)+\cdots;$$in particular, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Thank you for this fab explanation! It transpires it was my lack of Mathematica ability that was confusing me, which thankfully is easily rectified.